# generate route for routes defined inside group

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have this route defined inside a group

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.test.com'], function () {

    Route::get('/models/{id?}', [
        'as' => 'car-model',
        'uses' => 'CarModelController@details'
    ]);

});
```

I want to avoid hardcoding URLs in blade

```
{{route('car-model', 'ford', '100) }}
```

but that returs this url

```
ford.test.com/models
```

no model id!

Not sure if is relevant but in my controller CarModelController.php
I defined

```
public function details($subdomain, $id)
```

why is not sending the id to the generated url? Do I need to send the $subdomain parameter to the detail function?

Comment: Can you post your `CarModelController` route, and any groups it's attached to? What happens when you output `func_get_args()`? Are you seeing your id or your subdomain in there?

Answer (score 0):

I found that

```
{{route('car-model', ['make' => 'ford', 'id' => '100]) }}
```

works! thanks for watching :)